# Neo4j Cypher - How to display graph of all nodes of a certain type with a common node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

ie all nodes that are attached to the node with the name "Immunodeficiency" and also attached to the node with the name "autosomal recessive"

I tried this:

```
MATCH (a)-[r*]->(b)
WHERE a.name="Immunodeficiency" AND b.name="autosomal recessive"
return a,r,b
```

But it's not working. It's just returning a and b without any relationships or nodes in between

Comment: somebody pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return the paths

```
MATCH p=(a)-[r*]->(b)
WHERE a.name="Immunodeficiency" AND 
b.name="autosomal recessive"
return p
```

Comment: I have a followup question: How come when I do this:
    MATCH p=(a)-[r*]->(b)-[r*]->()
    WHERE a.name="immunodeficiency" and b.name="complement deficiencies"
    return p

Comment: But when I do this it works: MATCH p=(b)-[r*]->()
WHERE b.name="complement deficiencies"
return p